# Custom CSS for dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

For my dropdown box I have added custom css which was extracted from [Codepen project](https://codepen.io/yy/pen/vOYqYV) .

This is my HTML

```
<div class="size  ">
    <form action="#">
        sort by:
        <select name="size" id="sort-by" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Source Type">
            <option value="price-asc" {{ app('request')->input('sort')=='price-asc'?'selected':''}}>Price: Lowest first</option>
            <option value="price-desc" {{ app('request')->input('sort')=='price-desc'?'selected':''}}>Price: Highest first</option>
            <option value="name-asc" {{ app('request')->input('sort')=='name-asc'?'selected':''}}>Product Name: A to Z</option>
            <option value="name-desc" {{ app('request')->input('sort')=='name-desc'?'selected':''}}>Product Name: Z to A</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the custom css extracted from codepen project

```
 /** Custom Select **/
.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}
  .custom-select-wrapper select {
    display: none;
  }
  .custom-select {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    .custom-select-trigger {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 130px;
      padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 60px;
      background: #5c9cd8;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
      .custom-select-trigger:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 10px; height: 10px;
        top: 50%; right: 25px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
      }
      .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
        margin-top: 3px;
        transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
      }
  .custom-options {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  .custom-select.opened .custom-options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
    .custom-options:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
      bottom: 100%; right: 25px;
      width: 7px; height: 7px;
      margin-bottom: -4px;
      border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      background: #fff;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .option-hover:before {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .custom-option {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 0 22px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #b5b5b5;
      line-height: 47px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-option:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    .custom-option:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }
    .custom-option:hover,
    .custom-option.selection {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
```

This is the JavaScript extracted from codepen

```
 $(".custom-select").each(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
      id = $(this).attr("id"),
      name = $(this).attr("name");
  var template =
      '<div class="' +
      $(".custom-select").each(function() {
        var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
            id = $(this).attr("id"),
            name = $(this).attr("name");
        var template = '<div class="' + classes + '">';
        template +=
          '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' +
          $(this).attr("placeholder") +
          "</span>";
        template += '<div class="custom-options">';
        $(this)
          .find("option")
          .each(function() {
          template +=
            '<span class="custom-option ' +
            $(this).attr("class") +
            '" data-value="' +
            $(this).attr("value") +
            '">' +
            $(this).html() +
            "</span>";
        });
        template += "</div></div>";

        $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after(template);
      });
  $(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(
    function() {
      $(this)
        .parents(".custom-options")
        .addClass("option-hover");
    },
    function() {
      $(this)
        .parents(".custom-options")
        .removeClass("option-hover");
    }
  );
  $(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
    $("html").one("click", function() {
      $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
    });
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select")
      .toggleClass("opened");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select-wrapper")
      .find("select")
      .val($(this).data("value"));
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-options")
      .find(".custom-option")
      .removeClass("selection");
    $(this).addClass("selection");
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select")
      .removeClass("opened");
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select")
      .find(".custom-select-trigger")
      .text($(this).text());
  });
  classes + '">';
  template +=
    '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' +
    $(this).attr("placeholder") +
    "</span>";
  template += '<div class="custom-options">';
  $(this)
    .find("option")
    .each(function() {
    template +=
      '<span class="custom-option ' +
      $(this).attr("class") +
      '" data-value="' +
      $(this).attr("value") +
      '">' +
      $(this).html() +
      "</span>";
  });
  template += "</div></div>";

  $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).after(template);
});
$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(
  function() {
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-options")
      .addClass("option-hover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-options")
      .removeClass("option-hover");
  }
);
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $("html").one("click", function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this)
    .parents(".custom-select")
    .toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this)
    .parents(".custom-select-wrapper")
    .find("select")
    .val($(this).data("value"));
  $(this)
    .parents(".custom-options")
    .find(".custom-option")
    .removeClass("selection");
  $(this).addClass("selection");
  $(this)
    .parents(".custom-select")
    .removeClass("opened");
  $(this)
    .parents(".custom-select")
    .find(".custom-select-trigger")
    .text($(this).text());
});
```

Dropdown is working perfectly . But its **options display beyond other elements**. Please see the below image.

[image: Screen shot of current view]

So could anyone please tell me whats wrong in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely an issue of `z-index`. Searching your CSS doesn't show any mention of it, which would make it follow the static flow, which means it would be shown under any subsequently-placed or higher z-index elements.

The linked example doesn't have any other elements on the page, so this isn't a problem. Changing the `z-index` of the popup element to something arbitrarily large may fix the problem.

<sub>(Originally a comment but solved the question, posting here for future visitors.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Using z-index and setting it to a higher value for instance  99 should get your element to the top. 
z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).